# How to interpect when a coroutine in an observable has finished?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have an observable in my foreground service which fetch data from a paging API and save it to the database, the foreground service shows a notification with a progress bar with number of saved items vs the total amount.

Observable which fetch all the data looks like this:

```
private fun getAllProducts(): Observable<Response<List<ProdottoBarcode>>> {
    val lastId = intArrayOf(0)

    return Observable.range(1, Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1)
        .concatMap { currentPage -> getProducts(currentPage, lastId[0]) }
        .takeUntil { response -> response.body()?.isEmpty() == true }
        .doOnNext { response ->
            lastId[0] = response.headers().get("lastId")?.toInt()!!
        }
}
```

Then the subscription is done in onCreate() like this:

```
override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    ...
        getAllProducts().subscribeWith(object: DisposableObserver<Response<List<ProdottoBarcode>>>() {
        override fun onNext(response: Response<List<ProdottoBarcode>>) {
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                val products = response.body()
                val totalItems = response.headers().get("items")?.toInt()
                insertProducts(totalItems, products)
            }
        }

        override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
            stopService()
        }

        override fun onComplete() {
        }

    })
}
```

And the method which saves all the data to the database looks like this:

```
private fun insertProducts(totalItems: Int?, products: List<ProdottoBarcode>?) {
    if (products != null) {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            for (product in products) {
                repository.insert(product)
                savedItems += 1

                val notification =
                    totalItems?.let { items ->
                        NotificationCompat.Builder(baseContext, "progress_channel")
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_box)
                            .setContentTitle("Sincronizzati: $savedItems prodotti su $totalItems")
                            .setProgress(items, savedItems, false)
                            .setOngoing(true)
                            .build()
                    }

                notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification)
            }

            // TODO: stop the service and dismiss the notification when all items has been saved
            if (savedItems == totalItems) {
                stopService()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `stopService()` in `insertProducts` not always works, while if I try to put `stopService`  in `onComplete()` it will be executed once all subscriptions are done and **NOT** when all the items has been saved.

So my question is:

How can I stop my services by using the Coroutine inside the Observable? I need to know when all items from all observables are insert in database and only then to dismiss the service.

Comment: Kind of messy to mix Rx and coroutines back and forth like that. I would stick with one or the other. You can convert Rx to coroutine Flows pretty easily using one of the Reactive dependencies: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/reactive/README.md or conversely you could simply not use coroutines and use Rx exclusively for the background work.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I've changed my rx to `coroutines-rx3` so my `getAllProducts` now return a Flowble, but how I have to manage the Coroutine in `insertProducts`?

Comment: Sorry, I barely know Rx at all. If you were going in the other direction towards using coroutines and Kotlin Flows I could help with those details.

Comment: @Tenfour04 could you make an example by using coroutines?

Comment: @Tenfour04 I've just created an example by using Flow, is that the way? https://pastebin.com/YM2ymCkS

Comment: No, you shouldn't create a new CoroutineScope to collect a flow unless you are hanging onto that scope reference and cancelling it when the relevant screen is destroyed. Otherwise, the coroutine will run forever, leaking everything that is touched by its collector (usually and Activity or Fragment and all associated views). I'll add a coroutine example when I have some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Side note: you don't need to do Int wrapping like this in Kotlin like you would in Java. Kotlin has implicit variable wrapping, so you can simply use a `var` local variable and it will be captured by whatever function you use it in.

```
val lastId = intArrayOf(0)  // can just be var lastId = 0
```

---

Starting with `getProducts()` for fetching a page. I think the code you linked is OK provided your Retrofit service's `getProducts` function is marked suspend, so it's not blocking. No changes here.

```
private suspend fun getProducts(
        page: Int,
        lastId: Int,
        itemsPerPage: Int = 50
    ): Response<List<ProdottoBarcode>> {
        val prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
        val urlServer = prefs.getString("server", "http://127.0.0.1/")!!
 
        return RetrofitClient.getInstance().getService()
            .getProducts(urlServer, "A", page, lastId, itemsPerPage)
    }
```

Your `getAllProducts` in your linked code doesn't need backing StateFlows that are never collected--you're using them simply as mutable Int wrappers, which are unnecessary in Kotlin as mentioned way above. I'm not exactly sure how you're consuming these pages, since I'm not very familiar with Rx, but I take the use of `concatMap` to mean that the Observable is queuing up pages as fast as it can into a buffer, and you are reading out these pages to some local property that the UI uses.  I think a buffer should be added so we can be inserting in the database in parallel with fetching the next page. Default buffer arguments are probably appropriate.

```
private val allProducts: Flow<Response<List<ProdottoBarcode>>> = flow {
    var lastId = 0
    for (currentPage in 1 until Int.MAX_VALUE) {
        emit(getProducts(currentPage, lastId))
        lastId = response.headers().get("lastId")!!.toInt()
    }
}
    .takeWhile { response -> !response.body().isNullOrEmpty() }
    .buffer()
```

Usually, when you collect your flow, you should use an appropriate coroutine scope provided by the Android framework, so it will automatically cancel collection once it goes out of scope. If you inherit your service from LifecycleService, you can use the existing `lifecycleScope`. This is maybe not so critical in a service in this case, since I think you are only calling `stopService()` when your flow is complete, but it would make it a little more robust against potential mistakes, I think.

`.launchIn` is a shortcut that is like wrapping everything above it in `launch` and calling `collect()` on it. I prefer the syntax because it has less nesting of code.

```
override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    // ...

    allProducts.onEach { response ->
        if (response.isSuccessful) {
            val products = response.body()
            val totalItems = response.headers().get("items")?.toInt()
            insertProducts(totalItems, products)
        }
    }
        .catch { Log.e(TAG, "Failed collecting page.", it) }
        .onCompletion { stopService() }
        .flowOn(Dispatchers.Default) // don't use main thread since this is a service
        .launchIn(lifecycleScope)
}
```

Since we're using `buffer()` in the fetching flow, we don't need to launch other coroutines when inserting in the database to achieve parallelism. We can simplify this into a suspend function. We are handling stopping the service in the flow collector, so we don't need to do that here either. I'm assuming `repository.insert` is a suspend function, not blocking.

```
private suspend fun insertProducts(totalItems: Int?, products: List<ProdottoBarcode>?) {
    if (totalItems == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Tried to insert items without any item count. Skipping.")
        return
    }
    if (products == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Tried to insert null products list. Skipping.")
        return
    }
    for (product in products) {
        repository.insert(product)
        savedItems += 1
        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(baseContext, "progress_channel")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_box)
            .setContentTitle("Sincronizzati: $savedItems prodotti su $totalItems")
            .setProgress(items, savedItems, false)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .build()
        }
        notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification)
    }
}
```

Comment: I've used `takeWhile` instead `takeUntil` and added `LifecycleService` usage to my Service, all works like a charm, the complete code can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/bnB1NdJm)

Comment: Ah right, missed that conversion from Rx, fixed it above.